# Does Tensorflow Dataset API totally get rid of feed_dict argument?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm starting using Dataset API to replace the feed_dict system.

However, after creating your Dataset pipeline, how can you feed the Dataset's data to the model without using feed_dict ?

First, I created a one shot iterator. But in this case, you need to use feed_dict to provide the data coming from your iterator to the model.

Secondly, I tried to create my dataset directly from a tf.placeholder and then use a initializable_iterator. But here again, I don't understand how to get rid of feed_dict. In addition, I don't understand what's the purpose of this kind of dataset based on plaeholders.

My very basic model:

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
dense = tf.layers.dense(x, 1)
init_dense = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

My data:

```py
np_data = np.random.sample((100,2))
```

Method 1:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np_data)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_value = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_glob)

  for i in range(100):
    value = sess.run(next_value)
    # Cannot get rid of feed_dict
    result = sess.run(dense, feed_dict({x: value})
```

Method 2:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_value = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_glob)
  sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={x: np_data})

  for i in range(100):
    value = sess.run(next_value)
    # Cannot get rid of feed_dict
    result = sess.run(dense, feed_dict({x: value})
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/overview#input_pipeline

So, how can I "Avoid using feed_dict for all but trivial examples" ?
I think I didn't understand the concept of Dataset API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we need not use `feed_dict` if using the dataset api.

Instead we can just apply the dense layer to `next_value` each time.

Something like this:

```py
def model(x):
  dense = tf.layers.dense(x, 1)
  return dense

result_for_this_iteration = model(next_value)
```

so your full toy example, might look something like this:

```py
def model(x):
  dense = tf.layers.dense(x, 10)
  return dense

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.sample((100, 2, 2)))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_value = iterator.get_next()

result_for_this_iteration = model(next_value)


with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  while(True):
    try:
      result = sess.run(result_for_this_iteration)
      print (result)
    except OutOfRangeError:
      print ("no more data")
```

Of course, additional configuration options abound. We can `repeat()` so that we dont reach the end of the data but loop over it. We can `batch(n)` into batches of size `n`. We can `map(pre_process)` to apply a `pre_process` function to each element, etc.

Comment: Ok thank you very much I understood ! Then, what's the prupose to create a dataset from a placeholder ?

Comment: no purpose in creating a dataset from a placeholder - well, at least none that I know of... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯